# Make vbs wait until a time and then run a batch script

Tags: vbscript

I want to make a vbscript that waits until its 11:00AM and when it turns that time i want it to launch a batch script. I only know how to use

```
WScript.Sleep
```

But i want to make it run at a certain time.

Comment: Have you considered using the windows task scheduler? It may be easier to do what you want.

Comment: Thanks! good suggestion but I'm putting this on a flash drive and i don't want to use task scheduler for every computer I'm using this on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check system time with `Now()`:

```vb
Dim time, WshShell
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
time = Now()
hm = Minute(time) + 100 * Hour(time)
' Only execute between 11:00AM and 11:30AM
While hm < 1100 Or hm > 1130
    WScript.Sleep 2
    time = Now()
    hm = Minute(time) + 100 * Hour(time)
Wend
' Do your job here
WshShell.Run "some.bat", , False
```

Comment: When i clicked on the script it just ran without waiting :/

Comment: @JakeSixth Use `MsgBox` to determine the value of `hm`.

Comment: i tried Msgbox("hm = ",0, "wow") but i just got a error saying i cannot use a parentheses when calling a sub.

Comment: @JakeSixth You should directly write `MsgBox hm`

Comment: im getting 2331

Comment: @JakeSmith Hey, you stated **11:00AM**. OK I'm gonna update the answer.

Comment: how would i change this to pm for testing?

Comment: @JakeSmith Just modify `1100` and `1130` to your desired time (24h format).

Comment: alright thanks A lot! Sorry if i was tedious, im not that familiar with vbscripts. im a lot better with batch.